# data mining in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Ii am using matlab for data mining with three different algorithms. as you know every algorithm has a specific error. my question is how canIi able to write a code in matlab which find a minimum of error automatically and show commend like this "this algorithm has a minimum of error with x error"?
my code in matlab:

```
DecisionTree =
ClassificationTree
PredictorNames: {1x4 cell}
ResponseName: 'Y'
ClassNames: {1x3 cell}
ScoreTransform: 'none'
CategoricalPredictors: []
NumObservations: 150
Properties, Methods
>> view(DecisionTree,'mode','graph')
>> resubLoss(DecisionTree)
ans =
0.0200
NB = NaiveBayes.fit(meas,species)
NB =
Naive Bayes classifier with 3 classes for 4
dimensions.
Feature Distribution(s):normal
Classes:setosa, versicolor, virginica
>> z = NB.predict(meas);
>> ErrorNB = confusionmat(z,species)
ErrorNB =
50 0 0
0 47 3
0 3 47
1-sum(diag(ErrorNB))/sum(sum(ErrorNB))
ans =
0.0400
resubLoss(KNN)
ans =
0
```

as you see I have tree amount of error:0.02,0.04 and 0.